# Why tell about a past event with "would" although it was not repetitive in the past?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language, will-would

From the BBC web site about a famous comedian who passed away [Paul](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-65107949)

**"After making his mark on London's comedy scene as Lily Savage, O'Grady would go on to become one of the most recognisable faces on TV."**

The use of "would" caught my attention. Why **"....would go on to become...."** instead of **"....went on to be become..."?**

The sentence is telling about the past, and it is not a habitual action to become famous, which would have justified the use of "would"?.

So, what is the function of **"would"** in this sentence? Why tell about a past event with **"would"** although it was not habitual or a repetitive action in the past?

Comment: It's not *habitual* "would" in your cited context - it's ***future in the past***. Where *O'Grady **would** go on to become...* is a slightly more "literary" alternative to *O'Grady **was to** go on to become..* Note that both of these are only used when the *temporal focus* of the text centres on a point in past time - otherwise it would just be Simple Past *O'Grady **went on** to become...*

Comment: See also [Why do we express Past Simple Tense in such ways?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229170/why-do-we-express-past-simple-tense-in-such-ways) - specifically the *second* utterance being queried: *She **would eventually receive** a settlement of 1.5 million dollars.* Alternative phrasing for *She **was to** receive...* or plain *She **received...***